# Find the solution to the recurrence relation: $a_n=3a_{n-1}+1; a_0=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$a_n=3a_{n-1}+1; a_0=1$$

The book has the answer as: $$\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$$

However, I have the answer as: $$\frac{3^{n}-1}{2}$$

Based on:

[image]

Which one is correct?

Using backwards substitution iteration, the end of this will be 
$$3^{n-1}a_0+3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+...+3+1$$

which is $$=3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+...+3+1=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i$$

Which according to the theorem should be $$\frac{3^{(n-1)+1}-1}{(3-1)}=\frac{3^{n}-1}{2}$$

Comment: Try $n=0$, it should be 1

Comment: When the index $j=n$ the sum have $n+1$ terms, and no are $n$-terms, i think is this your confusion.

Comment: How did you get your solution? You can use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that "backwards substitution" is not a great way to solve this sort of thing, there are much better methods which I assume you will learn at some stage in your course.

However if you want to do it this way you can, only your working is not accurate.  Try this:
$$\eqalign{a_n
  &=3a_{n-1}+1\cr
  &=3(3a_{n-2}+1)+1\cr
  &=3^2a_{n-2}+3+1\cr
  &=\cdots\cr
  &=3^ka_{n-k}+3^{k-1}+\cdots+3+1\cr
  &=\cdots\cr
  &=3^na_0+3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\cdots+3+1\cr
  &=3^n+3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\cdots+3+1\cr
  &=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\ .\cr}$$
The third last line is where you went wrong, you stopped one step too soon.

Comment: I think the the first term on the third to the last line should be $3^{n-1}$ since that line would be $a_1$

Comment: You could do that, but it would be $3^{n-1}a_1$, not $3^{n-1}a_0$ as in your answer.  Then you could go one step further by substituting $a_1=3a_0+1$.

Comment: Is there a name to the better method?

Comment: The problem is called a *non-homogeneous recurrence relation*.  If you use the search box you will find  many references to it on MSE, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335369) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433964) for example.

Comment: I don't understand why we have $3^n$ if we are making $n-1$ substitutions.

Comment: We are making $n$ substitutions.  Suggestion: write out the whole procedure to get from $a_3$ down to $a_0$.  You will see that you have to make three substitutions, not two, and the answer will involve $3^3a_0$, not $3^2a_0$.

Comment: I made two substitutions.  We subbed $a_2$ to express $a_n$ in terms of $a_1$, then we subbed $a_1$ to express $a_n$ in terms of $a_0$.

Comment: But first you substituted $a_3=3a_2+1$ to get $a_3$ in terms of $a_2$.  This **is** a substitution even though it's given.  (Perhaps it would be better to use a different word, maybe "reduction" instead of "substitution".)  And in any case, when you did the algebra, what did you get at the end, $3^2a_0$ or $3^3a_0$?

Comment: thats right. $3^3a_0+3^2+3+1$

Comment: Exactly!  If you substitute $n=3$ in your original answer you get $3^2a_0+3+1$, which as you can see is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Write $b_n= a_n +\alpha$ and find $\alpha$ such that the recurrence reduces to $b_{n+1}=3b_n$. You'll find that $\alpha=1/2$ works. Then of course $b_n=3^nb_0=3^n(a_0+\alpha)$ and $a_n=b_n-\alpha=3^na_0+(3^n-1)\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is incorrect, since it fails for $n=0$.

Comment: there is another example in another section similar to this but instead the example says $H_n=2H_{n-1}+1$. The answer was $2^n-1$. I don't get it.

Comment: @Lanfranco It depends on your initial starting value $H_0$ and this case $a_0$.

Comment: but I was using the theorem, I added some info.

Answer (score 0):

According to yours $$a_0=0$$ so the book's is correct.

Comment: there is another example in another section similar to this but instead the example says $H_n=2H_{n-1}+1$. The answer was $2^n-1$. I don't get it.

Comment: @Lanfranco Then probably they had $H_0=0$. It all depends on the initial condition (don't worry it messes me up all the time two).

Comment: initial condition was $H_1=1$

Comment: @Lanfranco That is roughly the same. If $H_1=1$ then we could say that $H_0=(H_1-1)/2=0/2=0$. The point is that the initial condition is what determines the "loose constants" in the closed formula for any recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Ok your answer is correct, but   you have the formula for the $(n-1)$-term, if you need the formula for the $n$-term, then note that, according to recurrence

$$a_n=3a_{n-1}+1$$

You have that $$a_{n-1}=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$ then:
$$a_n=3\cdot\frac{3^n-1}{2}+1=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$$

God bless