# $u_1=1, u_{n+1}=2u_n+1$, prove that $u_{n}=2^n-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

[image]

Prove that $u_{n}=2^{n}-1$ for all positive integers $n$, by induction or what means?

What I did was sub $u_{n}=2^{n}-1$ into the $u_{n+1}$, but that got me nowhere. so what options do i have now.

Comment: Please [don’t use 
images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of [typing your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving a Recurrence Relation/Equation, is there more than 1 way to solve this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106036/solving-a-recurrence-relation-equation-is-there-more-than-1-way-to-solve-this) or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/797899 or [many similar posts](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24u_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3Dau_n%2Bb%24&p=1)

Comment: Can you include in your post what you obtained when doing this substitution? You are wrong in saying that got you nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods you could use to solve this problem.

### Method 1

Proof by induction:

**Base case**

First, we verify the base case where $n = 1$.

According to the sequence definition, $u_1 = 1$.

Now, let's check the formula $u_n = 2^n - 1$ for $u_1 = 1$:

$2^1 - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1$.

So the base case holds

**Inductive step**

Assume true for $n=k$ (where $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$), so $u_k = 2^k - 1$.

When $n=k+1$
$$u_{k+1} = 2^{k+1} - 1$$

Remember that the recurrence relation $u_{k+1} = 2u_k + 1$.

Substituting the inductive hypothesis $u_k = 2^k - 1$ into the recurrence relation, we get:

$$u_{k+1} = 2(2^k - 1) + 1$$
$$= 2^{k+1} - 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^{k+1} - 1$$

Since $u_1$ was shown to be true and it was also shown that if the formula is true for $n=k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, it is also true for $n=k+1$, it follows by the principle of mathematical induction that the formula is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

### Method 2

We can also prove it by examining the pattern established by the recursive definition:

$$u_{n+1} = 2u_n +1$$

This implies that
$$u_n = 2u_{n-1} + 1$$

Now let us try to derive an expression for $u_n$ in terms of earlier and earlier sequences until we spot a pattern
$$u_n = 2u_{n-1} + 1$$
$$= 2(2u_{n-2}+1) + 1$$
$$= 2^2u_{n-2}+ 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^2(2u_{n-3}+1)+ 2 + 1$$
$$= 2^3u_{n-3}+ 2^2 + 2 + 1$$
$$\ldots$$
$$ = 2^ku_{n-k}+ 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + \ldots + 1$$
$$ u_n = 2^ku_{n-k}+ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^k$$

Substituting $k=n-1$

$$ u_n = 2^{n-1}u_{n-(n-1)} + \sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)-1} 2^{i}$$
$$ = 2^{n-1}u_{n-n+1}+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1-1} 2^{i}$$
$$ u_n= 2^{n-1}u_{1}+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i}$$

$u_1 = 1$, so we can simplify the expression to

$$ u_n= 2^{n-1}+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i} $$  $\label{E:1}$

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i}$ is an geometric series with $u_1 = 1$ and $r = 2$.

We can substitue these valeus into the formula for the sum of a finite geometric sequence summation $$s_n = \frac{u_1(r^n - 1)}{r-1}$$ to find a simpler expression for $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i}$

It is important to note that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i} = S_{n-1}$, not $S_{n-2}$ as there are $n-1$ terms since the summation starts from $i=0$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i} = S_{n-1}$$
$$ = \frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{2-1}$$
$$ = \frac{2^{n-1} - 1}{1}$$
$$ = 2^{n-1} - 1$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i} = 2^{n-1} - 1$$

Substituting back into $u_n$:
$$ u_n= 2^{n-1}u_{1}+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{i}$$
$$ = 2^{n-1}+ 2^{n-1} - 1$$
$$ = 2(2^{n-1})- 1$$
$$ u_n = 2^{n}- 1$$

I personally like method 2 more, as method 1 does involve some level of circular reasoning (i.e. using the result you are trying to show in your proof) which I don't really like

Comment: Besides showing no effort, this post was a megaduplicate (see links above), and your two methods (among others) were already given on this site, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106061).

Comment: Really? No effort? For one it took me at least an hour to solve this question by hand, and then type it up in MathJax. And to your other point, you're right my methods were already given. So what? My writeup was much more well written and clear, making sure not to skip over any step. Please don't say my answer showed no effort...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! The *question* was "no effort", not your answer. On this site, we try to let the askers improve their post before answering, and to not duplicate answers (the many ones about this question were already redundant and very sufficient). Admittedly, it is not as rewarding to search for similar older post as to type a new answer...

Comment: Apologies then @Anne. Got a bit worked up there 